# Convert a Javascript Date format to desired PHP format

Tags: php, javascript

How can we convert  Wed Jun 09 2010 which is returns from a javascript function and get in a php script.I need to convert this date format to 2010-06-09.Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<?php
$jsDateTS = strtotime($jsDate);
if ($jsDateTS !== false) 
 date('Y-m-d', $jsDateTS );
else
 // .. date format invalid
```

Comment: Nice because you are also checking the invalid date format.

Answer (score 11):

Or with [DateTime](http://de.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('Wed Jun 09 2010');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

The date format you can input to `strtotime()`, `DateTime`  and `date_create()` are [explained in the PHP manual](http://de.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php). If you need more control over the input format and have PHP5.3, you can use:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M m Y', 'Wed Jun 09 2010');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 4):

Either you can send the javascript date to php via query string:

```
var mydate = encodeURIComponent('Wed Jun 09 2010');
document.location.href = 'page.php?date=' + mydate;
```

**PHP**

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(urldecode($_GET['date'])));
```

Or though a hidden field:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(urldecode($_POST['date'])));
```